# Rails: How to download a previously uploaded document?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, download, carrierwave

I need my user to upload documents such ad pdf and txt on their profile. And I did that using Carrierwave, so I have a list of documents with titles and urls.

**But how can I make other users download those files? Do I have to use a gem or is there something native I don't even know since I am very new to rails?**

Thanks

EDIT:

society.rb

```
class Society < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :documents, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

document.rb

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :society    
  mount_uploader :url, DocumentUploader    
end
```

And then this in the view I want to download files:

```
  <% @society.documents.each do |doc| %>
    <%= link_to "Download it", doc.url %>    //url is the column name of the saved url
  <% end %>
```

Comment: Maybe stupid question: how about handing the URLs your mention over to other users?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean =)

Comment: mmm I did it (see the edited question) but it still got me errors. I keep getting "undefined method `model_name' for DocumentUploader:Class" which is weird since i'm not uploading anything

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't use Carrierwave but I guess it's similar to Paperclip.

Therefore you should be able to use something like this

```
 link_to 'Download file', user.file.url
```

This is assuming you have a user instantiated object from a Model with a 'file' carrierwave attribute. Replace this with your attribute name.

Comment: I tried but i doesn't work, I'm sure I gettin something wrong.
I did like you said, (see in the edited question above)

Comment: Then try `doc.url.url` because your attribute is 'url' and you have to call the method 'url' on it. Hopefully 'url' isn't reserved by carrierwave, otherwise, change the name of your mount_uploader attribute

Comment: I am using Carrierwave gem and when i download the file, if that file name contains space then it's converted into underscores. So how to remove that underscore from the filename while downloading it ?

Answer (score 11):

You can use the [`send_file`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Streaming/send_file) method for this. Which could look like:

```
class MyController
  def download_file
    @model = MyModel.find(params[:id])
    send_file(@model.file.path,
          :filename => @model.file.name,
          :type => @model.file.content_type,
          :disposition => 'attachment',
          :url_based_filename => true)
  end
end
```

Check the apidock link for more examples.

Comment: I am using Carrierwave gem and when i download the file, if that file name contains space then it's converted into underscores. So how to remove that underscore from the filename while downloading it ?

Answer (score 0):

Or you can put anchor tag:

in your controller:

```
@doc = "query to get the document name from your database"
@docpath = request.base_url+"/uploads/"+@doc
```

in your view:

```
<a href="@docpath" download>Download File</a>.
```